# oAlt worked overtime

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

This is a cryptic crossword. The check mark will go to the first person who submits an answer with 1) an image of the completed crossword and 2) explanations for all clue answers. For users who cannot use Imgur, reproduce the completed crossword through table/code formatting.

[image: oAlt worked overtime grid]

**Across**

> 1. Perhaps Silicon Valley's Apple team finally meets current director (13)
> 9. Awkwardly posing, he left out something not meant to be said (4 2 3 6)
> 10. Saint converted young one, preventing from slipping (4-4)
> 11. Laugh at shop girl (6)
> 13. State damage obtained in ocean after grainy material covered central windows (3 6)
> 14. Urban area's "Absent Man", an imaginary figure (5)
> 15. Nothing to be found in department's warehouse (5)
> 17. Weak and incompetent, getting half of perfect score? (9)
> 19. Absolutely constant level in unit (6)
> 21. Cancelling an event's finale with lifeless surroundings (8)
> 24. Resume adding copper to your liquor, with one liter given to active organization (10 5)
> 25. Correct answer: "Cut the head of this crisp vegetable!" (5 8)

**Down**

> 1. A belt, one from Alexander (5)
> 2. No time's wasted in getting wet (7)
> 3. Go through a set of books about a pastry (9)
> 4. Fanatic briefly getting slower and slower, acquiring debts - good for the health? (10)
> 5. Applications of site in America, excluding tech field (4)
> 6. Revolutionary painting perhaps having no mineral (5)
> 7. Power and resistance brought up after leader's ousted in a series of... boat races (7)
> 8. Injured, take me in for drug (8)
> 12. This time, Herb ends career, making his room's interior cleaner (10)
> 13. Assistant on strike, opposing team (8)
> 14. Serve at small forests, with trees and shrubs along coasts (9)
> 16. Paragraph starter in retracted newspaper excerpt that leads to fight (7)
> 18. Integrated about islets - regularly happening (5-2)
> 20. A day gone: oAlt worked overtime for a dull one (5)
> 22. Customer that argues tips stores (5)
> 23. Uttered a sound (4)

Grid in table form:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |  | 5 |  | 6 |  | 7 | ■ | ■ |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 8 |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 11 |  |  |  |  |  |
| ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 12 | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 14 |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  |
| 15 |  | 16 |  |  | ■ | 17 |  |  |  |  |  | 18 |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ |
| 19 |  |  |  | 20 |  | ■ | 21 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 22 |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 23 | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 24 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| ■ | ■ | 25 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Hoping the title won't happen in real life. I want to relax after all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not easy to get into, but I liked the correct answer, Herb's room, the paragraph starter, the slowing down fanatic, the uttered sound and the awkward poser when I finally saw how they worked.

The grid:

> [image: Grid filled with the answers below]

Across

> 1.  **Perhaps Silicon** Valley's Apple team finally meets current director (13)
>   **SEMICONDUCTOR** = (valley)S + (appl)E + (tea)M + I ("current") + CONDUCTOR
>
>  9.  Awkwardly posing, he left out **something not meant to be said** (4 2 3 6)
>   **SLIP OF THE TONGUE** = (POSING HE LEFT OUT)*
>
>  10. Saint converted young one, **preventing from slipping** (4-4)
>   **ANTI-SKID** = SAINT* + KID
>
>  11. Laugh at shop **girl** (6)
>   **MARTHA** = MART + HA
>
>  13. **State** damage obtained in ocean after grainy material covered central windows (3 6)
>   **SAN MARINO** = SAN(d) minus (win)D(ows) + MAR ("damage") + IN + O(cean)
>
>  14. **Urban area**'s "Absent Man", an imaginary figure (5)
>   **MIAMI** = MIA (Missing in Action, so "absent") + M ("man") + I, found by juicifer
>
>  15. Nothing to be found in department's **warehouse** (5)
>   **DEPOT** = O ("nothing") in DEPT.
>
>  17. **Weak** and incompetent, getting half of perfect score? (9)
>   **UNTENABLE** = TEN (half of perfect 20, since a score of something = 20 of something) in UN.ABLE
>
>  19. Absolutely constant level in **unit** (6)
>   **KELVIN** = K ('kay, so "absolutely") + E (base of natural logarithm, so "constant") + LV ("level") + IN, with an &lit-tish touch
>
>  21. **Cancelling** an event's finale with lifeless surroundings (8)
>   **ABORTING** = even(T) in A + BOR.ING
>
>  24. **Resume** adding copper to your liquor, with one liter given to active organization (10 5)
>   **CURRICULUM VITAE** = CU in (IL (1 liter) in (UR ("your") + RUM)), all in ACTIVE*
>
>  25. Correct answer: "Cut the head of this **crisp vegetable**!" (5 8)
>   **WATER CHESTNUT** = (ANSWER CUT THE)* + T(his)

Down

> 1. A belt, one from **Alexander** (5)
>   **SASHA** (short form of Alexander) = SASH + A
>
>  2. No time's wasted in getting **wet** (7)
>   **MOISTEN** = (NO TIMES)*
>
>  3. Go through a set of books about a **pastry** (9)
>   **CROISSANT** = I in CRO.SS + A NT (New Testament, so "set of books")
>
>  4. Fanatic briefly getting slower and slower, acquiring debts - **good for the health**? (10)
>   **NUTRITIOUS** = NUT + RIT (ritardando = getting slower and slower in music) + IOUS
>
>  5. **Applications** of site in America, excluding tech field (4)
>   **USES** = S(it)E without IT in U.S
>
>  6. Revolutionary painting perhaps having no **mineral** (5)
>   **TRONA** = (ON in A.RT)<
>
>  7. Power and resistance brought up after leader's ousted in **a series of... boat races** (7)
>   **REGATTA** = ((w)ATTAGE + R)<
>
>  8. Injured, take me in for **drug** (8)
>   **KETAMINE** = (TAKE ME IN)*
>
>  12. This time, Herb ends career, making his room's interior **cleaner** (10)
>   **TOOTHBRUSH** = (r)OO(m) replaces (his) in (THIS + T + H(er)B + RUSH)
>
>  13. **Assistant** on strike, opposing team (8)
>   **SIDEKICK** = SIDE ("opposing team") + KICK
>
>  14. Serve at small forests, with **trees and shrubs along coasts** (9)
>   **MANGROVES** = MAN + GROVES
>
>  16. **Paragraph starter** in retracted newspaper excerpt that leads to fight (7)
>   **PILCROW** (a sign to mark a paragraph) = CLIP< + ROW
>
>  18. **Integrated** about islets - regularly happening (5-2)
>   **BUILT-IN** = (a)B(o)U(t) I(s)L(e)T(s) + IN ("happening")
>
>  20. A day gone: oAlt worked overtime for **a dull one** (5)
>   **IDIOT** = a D (day) removed from I ("oAlt") + DID ("worked") + OT ("overtime")
>
>  22. **Customer** that argues tips stores (5)
>   **GUEST** = ar(GUES T)ips
>
>  23. Uttered a **sound** (4)
>   **PURR** = sounds like "per" ("a")

Comment: 14 is zvffvat va npgvba + zna + gur vzntvanel havg

Comment: Well done. I knew someone else would complete it before I was half way through.

Comment: You're missing the I for current from 1A.

Comment: 10 across in your explanation should be ANTI-SKID :)

Comment: @juicifer: Oh, I see, thanks. (To the other "proofreaders", too, of course.)

Comment: Very nicely done (and thanks)! ROT13: 17N: ynggre jnf vagraqrq. "cresrpg" jnf cnegyl vagraqrq sbe gur fhesnpr, ohg ubcrshyyl vg'f fgvyy svar orpnhfr r.t. n cresrpg pvepyr vf fgvyy n pvepyr. 13Q: "bccbfvat grnz" = fvqr. 20Q: jbeqcynl jnf vagraqrq qvssreragyl, Q (qnl) vf tbar sebz V (bNyg) QVQ (jbexrq) BG (biregvzr)